# How to teach mariadb docker container not to start on the boot

Tags: docker, mariadb

I use docker-compose to bring up and down developer infrastructure on my workstation. Recently I found out that mariadb container starts itself after reboot. It creates volume in the project directory. Now I have to kill the container and rm -rf its volume each time I reboot, which is very annoying.

I've looked inside the container:

```
docker inspect docker_mariadb_1|grep -i -A5 policy
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
```

I need NO restart policy for containers in my workstation. How to teach mariadb container to start only by implicit request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be no restart policy by default, but you can set it manually `restart: "no"`

here is the documentation, it's under the point `restart`
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: I don't use docker-compose after reboot. Docker brings up mariadb on its own from downloaded docker image (which contains restart policy) with no usage of docker-compose.

Comment: I don't think you can set a restart policy on an image. but you can update the restart policy of your container, have you tried `docker update --restart=no <containerId> ?`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your're right the restart policy was set not in official mariadb image, but in docker-compose container definition. I've found `restart: always` in it. Now checking out. If it works I'll accept your answer.